# make a responsive css fullscreen 100% width, two rows three column grid (images background and text overlay)

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

Good Day Everyone.

I found help here for many many times and appreciate this platform a lot! Thanks to everyone!

This is my first question here and I probably asking for a bit too much.

I am trying to build a small "webapp" which shows current time, sunrise/sunset, weather and so on to train myself with javascript/APIs...

I'd like to build a full width grid [(please see screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6miTc.png).
So that it is always fullscreen no matter what desktop size. (On tablet if possible only two columns) and on smartphones 1colum fullwidth as well.
On every of the 6divs in the grid Id like to get a different backgroundimage and a centered overlay text for the data display. But this I could build.

I tried with bootstrap but didnt get what i wanted, so it would be awesome if this could be make with regular css. no margin, padding, space whatsoever.

Can anyone maybe please help me here? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please have a look on this link `https://jsfiddle.net/gxjowd7y/3/`

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
}

.box-a{
  background:green;
  height:50%;
}

.box-b{
  background:purple;
   height:50%;
}

.box-c{
  background:orange;
   height:50%;
}

.box-d{
  background:red;
  height:50%;
}

.box-e{
  background:gray;
   height:50%;
}

.box-f{
  background:blue;
   height:50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-a">

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-b">

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-c">

</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-d">

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-e">

</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box-f">

</div>
```

Comment: Wow! This is amazing and looks yet so simple. Im feeling a bit stupid now. Thank you so very very much mate! Awesome!